# Server at home with static public IP

Tags: networking, server, 64-bit, dns

Hi I have a problem with Ubuntu 12.04 Server.

I have checked the IFConfig it seems all the entries are correct except the nameservers do not seem to get resolved. As such when I run `/etc/int.d/networking restart` I receive an error message.:

> Failed ... eth0

I have been trying for a couple of days. I was given the static IP address and when I ping it is ok, i.e. no packages lost. However on the server I cannot access internet and webpages. I think I may have given incorrect values.

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (i iused the IP address given by ISP, not sure whether this is correct)
netmask 255.255.255.0
network xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (used the IP address given by ISP i.e. WAN IP)
broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.255 (combination of IP and subnet?)
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (got it from router)
dns-servers xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (provider by isp,obtained the values from router)
```

When I run `cat /etc/resolv.conf`, I do not see any values.

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your router has the ip 192.168.1.1 the configuration would be:
address 192.168.1.4 (for example)
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-servers (provider by isp)

Comment: Hi Smile Thank you for your detailed explanation. I believe we have a problem with name server. I've change the settings as per your information here after which  ran /etc/init.d/networking restart and the message "... deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces Reconfiguring network interfaces RTNETLINK answers: File exists Failes to bring up eth0" I have used another computer in the same network to connect to the computer via SFTP and the IP address of the other computer and it works.

Comment: Hi Smile 
Thank you for your detailed explanation. 
Config:
address 192.168.2.xx
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.2.0
broadcast 192.168.2.255
gateway 217.0.xxx.xxx(from router, isp)
dns-server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (from isp)

Ran /etc/init.d/networking restart 

The message "... deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces Reconfiguring network interfaces RTNETLINK answers: File exists Failes to bring up eth0" 

Managed to connect to the computer via SFTP and the IP from another computer in the same network.

Restarted computer but I'm unable to view webpages

Comment: Hi I have changed the gateway to 192.168.2.1 and i managed to connect to the internet and view web pages.

Comment: Its solved your problem?

Comment: It solved the web problem. I've just also tried with the public IP and it worked as well. I will try the public IP at home to see whether it works as well. For now two problems have been solved. Thank you!

Comment: :) happy to hear it. thx to you

Answer (score 2):

Since you connect through a router, "the IP address given by ISP" should not be in the interfaces config file. Routers usually use IPs of the following type 192.168.x.x or 10.x.x.x, depending on the router. These are [private IPs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), and they are always different from the ones assigned by ISPs. The result of putting such an IP into the config file is - you get no internal IP, as the router can't provide the one you ask for. There are numerous examples of the interfaces config file on the net. Here is one from the [LinuxJournal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/ubuntus-new-dns-unknown-host) you might find useful:

```
auto eth0  
iface eth0 inet static   
address 192.168.1.200   
netmask 255.255.255.0   
gateway 192.168.1.1   
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

The title seems irrelevant to the body of the question, but if you need a static public IP, either contact your ISP, or use services like [NOIP](http://www.noip.com/) or [DYNDNS](http://dyn.com/dns/dyndns-pro-free-trial/).

Comment: Hi Thank you for the detailes information. We do have a static public ip which is provided by the ISP and the ISP suggested us to also activate port forwarding on the router. Initially we did not change the network/interfaces file to static because we thought everything would work. We will try out your suggestion by changing the internal IP. We would let you know of the outcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your ISP gave you a static IP, the info for the static IP should be entered where the ISP cable is plugged. You say you take info from router so you have a router and the ISP cable is plugged in this router. The static IP must be configured on the router, not on your server. Your server should revceive local IP from your router (NAT) and you have to use port forwarding on the router to access the server from internet.

If you want the static IP on the server and not the router, you have to plug the ISP cable on the server.